# Getting "no valid OpenPGP data found" When trying to add public key to Win 2003 server

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have been 'emailed' a list of public PGP Keys:

> development: "ssh-rsa
>   AAASDHFhdfsdSDHF2SHdf932hSDF29SDFHSDF2SDFHSDF23SHDFewhw92sdfhSDFS29843SdhsdfZSDH=
>   some@bunk"
>
> staging: "ssh-rsa
>   AAASDHFhdfsdSDHF2SHdf932hSDF29SDFHSDF2SDFHSDF23SHDFewhw92sdfhSDFS29843SdhsdfZSDH=
>   more@bunk"
>
> production: "ssh-rsa
>   AAASDHFhdfsdSDHF2SHdf932hSDF29SDFHSDF2SDFHSDF23SHDFewhw92sdfhSDFS29843SdhsdfZSDH=
>   serious@bunk"

And asked to install them on a server that needs them for FTPing files to another server.

We have a Windows 2003 server and are using GPG. The encryption is AES 256.

To install the above, I have tried copying each individual "ssh-rsa" string and giving them their own text file (dev.txt, stag.txt, & prod.txt).

Then, I try importing the public keys into the local server's keyring (using dev.text, for example):

$gpg --import dev.txt

The result I get in all cases is always:

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.  gpg: Total number processed: 0

It won't work.

Am I adding the public keys to my server correctly? Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, all those keys seem to be the same, and second of all, you probably should not be putting them up here in the first place. maybe give some more info. you have the error message, but what leads up to it? at what stage does that happen?

Answer (score -1):

Those aren't GPG keys, they're SSH keys (and either very weak ones or incomplete).